# Saving pyspark dataframe with complicated schema in plain text for testing

Tags: pyspark

How do I make clean test data for pyspark? I have figured something out that seems pretty good, but parts seem a little awkward, so I'm posting.

Let's say I have a dataframe `df` with a complicated schema and a small number of rows. I want test data checked into my repo. I don't want a binary file. At this point, I'm not sure the best way to proceed -but I'm thinking i have a file like

```
test_fn.py
```

and it has this in it

```
schema_str='struct<eventTimestamp:timestamp,list_data:array<struct<valueA:string,valueB:string,valueC:boolean>>>'
```

to get the schema in txt format, using the `df.schema.simpleString()` function. Then to get the rows - I do

```
lns = [row.json_txt for row in df.select((F.to_json(F.struct('*'))).alias('json_txt')).collect()]
```

now I put those lines in my `test_fn.py` file, or I could have a `.json` file in the repo.

Now to run the test, I have to make a dataframe with the correct schema and data from this text. It seems the only way spark will parse the simple string is if I create a dataframe with it, that is I can't pass that simple string to the `from_json` function? So this is a little awkward which is why I thought I'd post -

```
schema2 = spark.createDataFrame(data=[], schema=schema_str).schema
lns = # say I read the lns back from above 
df_txt = spark.createDataFrame(data=lns, schema=T.StringType())
```

I see df_txt just has one column called 'value'

```
df_json = df_txt.select(F.from_json('value', schema=schema2).alias('xx'))
sel = ['xx.%s' % nm for nm in df_json.select('xx').schema.fields[0].dataType.fieldNames()]
df2 = df_json.select(*sel)
```

Now `df2` should be the same as `df1` - which I see is the case from the `deepdiff` module.